# MySQL applying filesort regardless of indexed columns in ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Why is MySQL choosing to apply a filesort in the execution plan for the query below ?
As I understand, filesort should only apply if the columns being sorted on are not part of the index.

The dataset itself is mere 10 rows, not enough to warrant adjusting resource parameters
like **innodb_buffer_pool_size**. The actual use-case where I want MySQL to not go for filesort is where a table like the 'A_LARGE_TABLE' has around 60 million rows. There is no need to force use the index since the index is already being used per the execution plan, just not when ordering.

How can I get this to use index rather than filesort for ordering ?

```
#DDL - Create first Table
CREATE TABLE A_LARGE_TABLE
(
    ID            BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    INTEGER_VALUE BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    TEXTUAL_VALUE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DOUBLE_VALUE  DOUBLE,
    INDEX (INTEGER_VALUE, DOUBLE_VALUE DESC, TEXTUAL_VALUE)
);

#DDL - Create second Table
CREATE TABLE LOOKUP_TABLE
(
    ID        BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SOME_DATA BIGINT NOT NULL
);

#seed some data in first table
INSERT INTO A_LARGE_TABLE(INTEGER_VALUE, TEXTUAL_VALUE, DOUBLE_VALUE)
VALUES (1, '1111111111', 2.2),
       (2, '2222222222', 5.2),
       (3, '3333333333', 2.2),
       (4, '4444444444', 56.2),
       (5, '5555555555', 25.5),
       (6, '6666666666', 21.2),
       (7, '7777777777', 25.2),
       (8, '8888888888', 342.2),
       (9, '9999999999', 29.2),
       (10, '1010101010', 32.2);

#seed some data in second table
INSERT INTO LOOKUP_TABLE(SOME_DATA)
VALUES (1),
       (2),
       (3),
       (4),
       (5),
       (6),
       (7),
       (8),
       (9),
       (10);

#Why does this lead to filesort ?
SELECT *
FROM A_LARGE_TABLE A
         JOIN LOOKUP_TABLE B ON A.INTEGER_VALUE = B.ID
ORDER BY A.DOUBLE_VALUE DESC, A.TEXTUAL_VALUE;
```

The resultant execution plan,

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "25.00"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "10.00"
      },
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "A",
            "access_type": "index",
            "possible_keys": [
              "INTEGER_VALUE"
            ],
            "key": "INTEGER_VALUE",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "INTEGER_VALUE",
              "DOUBLE_VALUE",
              "TEXTUAL_VALUE"
            ],
            "key_length": "1039",
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "using_index": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "1.00",
              "eval_cost": "2.00",
              "prefix_cost": "3.00",
              "data_read_per_join": "10K"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "ID",
              "INTEGER_VALUE",
              "TEXTUAL_VALUE",
              "DOUBLE_VALUE"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "B",
            "access_type": "eq_ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY"
            ],
            "key": "PRIMARY",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "ID"
            ],
            "key_length": "8",
            "ref": [
              "nfw_prod_db.A.INTEGER_VALUE"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "10.00",
              "eval_cost": "2.00",
              "prefix_cost": "15.00",
              "data_read_per_join": "240"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "ID",
              "SOME_DATA"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: This works as expected on MySQL v8, the sorting is carried out using index rather than filesort. We're on MySQL 5.7 and it goes to filesort there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is being "used" in the sense that it's doing an index-scan. This means it's going to examine every entry in the index, like a table-scan does for rows of the table. But an index-scan only needs to read the single index, not the rest of the table.

But it's not able to use the index for sorting because an index-scan reads the index in order by the first column, then by the second column in cases of ties, and so on.

That's not the same order you wanted the query result, so it can't rely on the order it reads the index entries to skip the filesort.

By analogy, think of a telephone book, which is sorted by `last_name` then by `first_name`. If you want the result sorted by `first_name`, the existing order of the telephone book is not helping. You would have to collect the results and sort them manually by `first_name`.

I tested your query on MySQL 8.0, and it still does a filesort. I don't know what test you ran that shows it can use this index to skip a filesort. I don't think it can, with the query you show in your question above.

In your table, if your index were on `(DOUBLE_VALUE DESC, TEXTUAL_VALUE, INTEGER_VALUE)`, then it could read the index in the order it is stored, and that would skip the filesort because it matches the order you specified in your query.

However, indexes with mixed DESC and ASC direction is not supported in MySQL 5.7. This was a new feature of 8.0 (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html). I don't think you can simulate this in MySQL 5.7.

On the other hand, MySQL 5.7 will be out of support by October 2023, so you should be thinking about upgrading to 8.0 soon regardless.

Comment: Turns out V5.7 works after all once DESC is removed per your recommendation. Marking this as the answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming the directions in the ORDER BY clause in the query you showed were required. I'm glad that you found your answer.